# How to use Python to implement: insert a paragraph of text and a picture at the beginning of a word file that already has content

Tags: python

How to use Python to implement: insert a paragraph of text and a picture at the beginning of a Word file that already has content

How I did it was to insert it at the end of the text. I tried adding text to the first paragraph, but it didn't work, but it can replace the first paragraph of text. As for adding the picture to the beginning, it didn't work either.

Please tell me how to achieve this requirement. The Word file itself has content. Now I want to insert it into the first paragraph.

This is my Python code:

```py
pic=r'D:\landrop\1.jpeg'
r=paragraphs[0].add_run()
r.add_text('xxx ')
r.add_picture(pic,width=Inches(5.0))
r.add_text('xxxx,')
r.add_text(text)
doc.save("Summary_output.docx")
```

Comment: Some context is missing. What is `paragraphs`?

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

# Open the existing Word document
doc = Document('existing_document.docx')

# Create a new paragraph with the desired text
new_paragraph = doc.add_paragraph('This is a new paragraph of text at the beginning.')

# Add a picture to the document
image_path = 'path_to_your_image.jpg'  # Replace with the path to your image file
doc.add_picture(image_path, width=Inches(2.0), height=Inches(2.0))

# Get the existing content of the document
existing_content = doc.paragraphs + doc.tables

# Clear the existing content from the document
for element in existing_content:
    p = element._element
    p.getparent().remove(p)

# Insert the new paragraph and picture at the beginning of the document
doc.paragraphs.insert(0, new_paragraph)

# Save the modified document
doc.save('modified_document.docx')
```

Replace 'existing_document.docx' with the path to your existing Word document, and 'path_to_your_image.jpg' with the path to the image you want to insert.

This script will open the existing Word document, clear its existing content, insert the new paragraph and picture at the beginning, and then save the modified document as 'modified_document.docx'.